# My console.log or window.alert isn't show up

Tags: reactjs, forms, registration, console.log

```
export default function RegisterForm(data) {
  const [username, setusername] = React.useState("");
  const [email, setemail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setpassword] = React.useState("");


  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
       window.location.reload(false);
       const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/register`,{
        method: 'POST',
        // headers: {
        //   'Accept': 'application/json',
        //   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        // },
        body: JSON.stringify({username: username, email: email, password: password })
      }).then((result)=>{
        result.json().then((resp)=>{
          window.alert(JSON.stringify(resp))
          console.warn(resp)

        })
      })
    
    event.preventDefault();
    
    setusername("");
    setemail("");
    setpassword("");
    
  }
```

So I am using this code to add an account to mysql and its actually working.My problem is that I can't see my console log.What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You use `await` and `.then` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by using `await` and `.then()` at the same time, try the following code -

```
export default function RegisterForm(data) {
  const [username, setusername] = React.useState("");
  const [email, setemail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setpassword] = React.useState("");


  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
       window.location.reload(false);
       const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/register`,{
        method: 'POST',
        // headers: {
        //   'Accept': 'application/json',
        //   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        // },
        body: JSON.stringify({username: username, email: email, password: password })
      })
      
        response.json().then((resp)=>{
          window.alert(JSON.stringify(resp))
          console.warn(resp)

        })
      
    
    event.preventDefault();
    
    setusername("");
    setemail("");
    setpassword("");
    
  }
```

Comment: Still doesn't show up.The crazy thing is that in another page that I have is working perfectly

Comment: can you post the code of the working page?

Comment: I post it down below, the delete part

Answer (score 0):

```
const getPartnersData = async () => {
    try {
          const data = await axios.get(
            "http://127.0.0.1:5000/getPartners"
          );
          setPartner(data.data);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        getPartnersData();
      }, []);

function deletePartner(name, id)
  {
    if(window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete  ' +name +'?',)){
      fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/deletePartner/" + id, 
        { method: 'DELETE'
      // headers: {
        // 'Accept': 'application/json',
         //'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // },
        
      }).then((result)=>{
        result.json().then((resp)=>{
          console.warn(resp)
          window.alert('Partner deleted successfully')
          getPartnersData();
        })
      })
  }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.reload(false);`

I believe this line reloads the page, even though if your POST call goes through, the fact that you called the function above actually clears the console.

We could note here that whenever the browser refreshes the page, it automatically clears the logs in the console.

What you could do/try however is to preserve the logs of the console if you are debugging in Chrome, there is an option to preserve the log as shown below:

[image: a demonstration of preserving the log]

As you can see above, you can opt to preserve the logs via the gear icon on the upper right hand corner of the console.

I hope this works regardless of the async function that you have.